# How to stop page from scroll when toggle text opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

Quick note : I have read other similar questions, but they are all about modal opening up as overlay on body and they want to stop scroll on body.

But in my case, when I open the toggle the page autoscrolls and I don't want that to happen I want it to stay at same place.

Here is the link ( http://isma.tomorrowing.today/ ) where you can see the issue in test text 2 or 3 section by clicking any of the 'Read Text' button.

I want the webpage to stay at some position even when toggle is opened.

Although I am using elementor in Wordpress on the website, but custom CSS or JS works for me as well.

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey Spectric, 100% valid point, but the whole thing is built using a plugin and there is no direct code of it, that I can share, otherwise I would have certainly done it. But thanks a lot for sharing this question. 

Although, just so you know, I created this whole page for this issue on the website as a reproduction of issue.

Comment: Not sure if it would help - But seems like you are using an `a` tag for the titles? there might be some complication with that, if elementor sees the empty href as a section to look for? 
No clue though

Comment: Only section 3 scrolls for me - Section 2 works fine in my browser - So that probably isn't the issue - So nevermind me

Comment: Not sure why section 2 not scrolling for you, might be screen size dependent, as section 1 with same properties won't scroll for me but 2 and 3 does, btw I am on a 13 inch screen. 

Also, I tried changing the a tag to p tag, but no difference, issue stays.

Comment: the size of a screen in inches have no influence on the websites behavior. The Viewport is measured in CSS-Pixels not in inches. So the resolution do matter as well as the difference between physical pixels (hardware pixels) and CSS pixels (software pixels). For mobile devices it is not the same.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I don't know why I commented inches, sorry and lol!